# Using Twilio Studio to Facilitate Anonymous P2P Messaging

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

We are using Twilio to offer a SMS service for people in our church and community that have a prayer request or other need. Currently, we are using Twilio Studio to handle receiving the SMS request and then relaying that to a random person on our Care Team.

I'd like to figure out a way for the people on our Care Team to be able to reply to the initial sender and have it be relayed through the Twilio number instead of by their personal cell phone number.

Is there a way within Twilio studio to monitor for these replies and tie them together through a session ID or something like that?

I am trying to keep everything as simple as possible and built within Twilio Studio so that it makes it easier for other people at the church to make updates/changes in the future.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Studio is not designed for 2-way Human-to-Human interactions for messaging. It is focused on Human-to-Bot, so you will to remove Studio from that interaction if it escalates to that format.

You could use a product like [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/conversations) that handles responses (rather then Studio doing this) to outbound SMS sent via Studio and the Rest API Trigger, so that responses programmatically set-up a 2-way interaction using the `Autocreate a new Session - Automatically set up a new Conversation for any sender not already in one` option for your messaging service, and the `onConversationAdded` Conversations Post-webhook, to be identified of this `onConversationAdded` event and programmatically connecting the parties together as SMS participants into this new conversation, say using a serverless Twilio Function to handle the logic to do so.

[Conversations Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations)

There is a blog using a Twilio Function to allow a 2-way conversation over SMS but it is not ideal for your use case, given the additional steps required to appropriately reply to each SMS, but I put it here for others that may be interested.

[SMS Forwarding and Responding Using Twilio and JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-forwarding-and-responding-using-twilio-and-javascript)

Alan

Comment: Using Twilio Studio and Conversations with SMS  - https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-twilio-studio-conversations-sms